# Unresolved external symbol "protected static struct" error despite being defined in a .cpp file

Tags: c++, static, unresolved-external

This is my eventhandler.h

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <Windows.h>

class EventHandler
{
public:

    EventHandler()
    {
    }

    ~EventHandler()
    {
    }

    static std::queue<MSG*> Events;
};
```

I've searched a lot to try and solve my problem and all the answers say to declare the static variable in a c++ file, which I've done

```
  #include "EventHandler.h"
  std::queue<MSG*> EventHandler::Events;
```

but I still get

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: static struct tagMSG * Entity::msg" (?msg@Entity@@1PAUtagMSG@@A)
```

and I can't figure out why. Have I missed something?

Comment: The error says `Entity::msg` is not defined, not `EventHandler::Events`. Can you provide the definition for `Entity` and its associated cpp?

Comment: That was the problem, I forgot that I had a static variable in a different class. Thank you for pointing that out. It helps if you read the error message more thoroughly

Comment: voted to close as "can no longer reproduce" since it's been solved

Answer (score 0):

You **also** need to place your static in cpp file:

```
// EventHandler.cpp
std::queue<MSG*> EventHandler::Events;
```